# Python Neurolab - fixing output range

Tags: python, neural-network

I am learning some model based on examples ${((x_{i1},x_{i2},....,x_{ip}),y_i)}_{i=1...N}$ using a neural network of Feed Forward Multilayer Perceptron (newff) (using python library neurolab). I expect the output of the NN to be positive for any further simulation of the NN. 
How can I make sure that the results of simulation of my learned NN are always positive? 
(how I do it in neurolab?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a standard sigmoid/logistic activation function on the output neuron. sigmoid(x) > 0 forall real-valued x so that should do what you want.

By default, many neural network libraries will use either linear or symmetric sigmoid outputs (which can go negative).

Just note that it takes longer to train networks with a standard sigmoid output function. It's usually better in practice to let the values go negative and instead transform the outputs from the network into the range [0,1] after the fact (shift up by the minimum, divide by the range (aka max-min)).

Comment: will this be equivalent to setting the transfer function of the output neuron to be a logistic activation function while the internal activation function be linear?

Comment: I highly recommend NOT using linear internal activation functions. The whole point of a neural network is that the composition of multiple non-linear activation functions allows the network to capture non-linearities in your data.

Using a linear activation function for your hidden layers will basically just give you a fancy logistic regression.

Instead, use symmetric sigmoid (or hyperbolic tangent) activations for your hidden layers and a logistic/sigmoid (same thing) for your output.

Comment: I misspeled. No linear sigmoid in the internal layers. The question was, what is preferable and why: 1) learning using at the output neuron a log sigmoid that will make the output in the range [0,1] (other neurons with other sigmoids, also non-linear) or 2) train the NN using a [-0.5,0.5] sigmoid at the output and shifting the output by offset with the min value and scaling with max-min.

Comment: Hidden layers:

Lots of linear relationships: use linear

nonlinearities (a logit didn't do very well): try symmetric sigmoid (this prevents very large weights which cause overfitting when you use a regular sigmoid activation)

If your data has logical decision boundaries (i.e. capturing a decision tree) then you'll want multiple hidden layers (2-3) with hyperbolic tangent activation functions (tend to capture boundaries more clearly)

Outputs:

Linear is often best for regressions

Logistic/Sigmoid (same thing, different names) if you want a binary classifier

Comment: I am learning a regression model. The target is actually probabilities and not classes. I actually have a good model for logistic regression (that calculates probabilities) and I am trying to beat its performance by NN. The problem is that the predictions of the NN have large values (closer to 1, after I included at the output neuron a log sigmoid). Do you have any specific recommendation for this case?

Comment: Ah, now I understand your problem. The outputs are very clustered around 1 with low variance (so that your predictions aren't very useful). 

Is the data sparse? (i.e. will the model easily revert to the 'always pick something close to 1' strategy? If so, resampling the data is worthwhile.

If not, you have a network topology problem. I'd try aiming for 1 hidden layer with half the number of hidden neurons as inputs. 

All else fails, using a linear activation and 'scaling it' (to interpret as a probability) could work.

Comment: The target data is not clustered around 1 (it is actually clustered around 0) since the probabilities represent the probabilities of long tail events. But after in the when using the model for the test parts it produces much higher probabilities. what you mean re-sampling? do you mean bootstraping? I am using a network of the form [10 5 1] , but the number of variables is much much higher like 250.

Comment: I am using Logarithmic sigmoid in the output neuron and Hyperbolic tangent sigmoid in all the other neurons. is that ok?

Comment: What you describe is *definitely* overfitting (if the model performs well and clusters around 0 for the training data but closer to 1 for the test data). I'd advise simplifying the topology to 10:2:1 and seeing how it works.

A good way to compare the effectiveness of models is to use AUC (Area under the ROC curve)... this will reveal any signs of overfitting.

Picking the wrong activation functions won't cause what you're seeing... it's definitely overfitting.

Comment: Might I ask what kind of data this is? It's possible a random forest will work better (neural networks are fantastic but require a lot of tweaking to prevent overfitting... I'd suggest bayesian regularized neural networks if you really want to go the neural-network route).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried in the past using RandomForest but it performed poorly, worst than logistic regression. I think that happened because all of my variables are categorical data, and I have plenty of them (250+). From my experience with lots of categorical variables trees don't perform so good. The data is counting data. This is marketing information, the input data represents characteristics of costumers and the target counts the ratio between entering a store and buying some product. so target is a probability.

Comment: Yeah, I'd definitely opt to turn that into a classification problem. So have your output be whether or not the product was bought (1=bought, 0=not bought). Then compare your models using the AUC (this checks all possible cutoffs that map the outputs to 1 or 0 and gives the false positive/true positive for each one). The R package ROCR is helpful for this. Scikit-Learn also has ROC curve/AUC plotting.

It's very likely that there's not a strong enough relationship in your data to do a regression.

I'd also check out Vowpal Wabbit: it's a linear learner that works well for categorical problems.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure about this approach. Since this is a counting problem, a costumer entering the store is a Bernoulli trial with probability p that he buy and 1-p that he doesn't. So trying to classify will give poor results on the ROC curve.

Comment: Rather than try to predict 'P' via a regression, you use the model to predict the event itself. It's simply a matter of then counting the total 'positives' vs. 'negatives' predicted by the model. No reason you would get worse AUC's this way. If the choice of ML algorithm is adequate, the distribution of total successes / total failures should approximate reality.

If you're set on capturing the underlying distribution correctly, then look into using restricted boltzmann machines (RBM) which capture the probability distribution of its neurons.

Comment: What I mean is that, take for example the following hypothetical samples, $(x_1,y_1=0),(x_2,y_2=1),...,(x_n=x_1,y_n=1),(x_{n+1}=x_1,y_{n+1}=0)$ see that for same inputs sometimes we got output 1 but otherwise (most of the time) we got zero. Then, after training the NN, since the network is deterministic I git got always  for the input $x=x_1$ an output of 1. What I am interested in,  is the probability that for a certain input I will get a value of one.

Comment: Computing the output with the test samples, wont lead to that probabilities, since the output will be either zero all the time or one, since the network will simulate the same output for a certain input.

Comment: Ah, I see. Typically, if you have enough inputs the determinism wouldn't be an issue (since there'll be enough variation in your inputs the model can actually capture something worthwhile). In your case, what you want is a bayesian style belief network then. A neural network as a regression is NOT the way to go... you won't have the right kind of data to make full use of it.

If you're set on Python, check this out: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pbnt.berlios/